# IE problems with PrintShop Mail Web

Tags: php, jquery, iframe

Anyone using PrintShop Mail Web? We're integrating it using a simple iframe, but the application keeps logging out.

We're also using a JQuery plugin called postmessage to aid in resizing the iframe according to the height of the content in it. Not sure if something in this plugin is causing the PrintShop website to reset it's authentication status.

This only happens in IE though, FF, Safari and Chrome don't behave this way.

Any help would really be appreciated

Regards,
Jacques

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because IE doesn't accept cookies that are set from an iframe see http://adamyoung.net/IE-Blocking-iFrame-Cookies for more background information.

You can easily fix this by adding a single line to the *template.php* file that you use, typically you can find the file here: "**C:\Program Files\PrintShop Mail Suite 7\PrintShop Mail Web\Website\templates\default\template.php**"

Just add `<?php header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"'); ?>` as the first line in the file, save it and refresh the browser that should fix it.